# AWS CLI How to check if images follows a special pattern tag value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to filter the images that follow the following pattern in their tag value: `dev/yyyy-mm-dd`
eg. : `dev/2021-09-11`

the best idea that came up to me was something like this:

`aws ec2 describe-images --filters Name=tag:tag_name,Values="dev/????-??-??"`

is there a more logical approach?

Comment: I'd recommend a small Python script that would call `describe_images()`, then check whether the tag value can be converted to a date.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Could you please elaborate on this? I have noticed that we can pipe python on top of the aws command, but not sure how to write it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the boto3 AWS SDK to call AWS directly, something like:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

FIND_TAG = 'your-tag'

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

images = ec2_resource.images.filter(Owners=['self'])

# Find the matching tag
for image in images:
  values = [tag['Value'] for tag in image.tags if tag['Key'] == FIND_TAG]

if len(values) > 0:
  value = values[0]

  # Is it a date?
  try:
    date = datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
  except ValueError:
    print('Not a date')
```